# javascript -> getAttribute in webdriver.io

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io

```
    var checkBoxes = await $$('.checkbox.moduleName') 
    console.log('length', $$('.checkbox.moduleName').length)
    checkBoxes.forEach((elem)=>{
        console.log(elem)
        console.log(elem.getAttribute('value'))
    })
```

This is my code. I have some checkboxes with class'.checkbox.moduleName'. When I print the length, it gets printed as 10. But then the getAttribute function does not work.

```
 TypeError: elem.getAttribute is not a function
at checkBoxes.forEach
```

How do I get the attribute 'value' for the checkboxes?

I tried this too

```
       var valueAttrs =
        checkBoxes
            .map(function(e){
                console.log('e', e)
                return e.getAttribute('value');
            });

    valueAttrs.forEach(v=>{console.log('value: ' + v);});
```

same error

This is the html line i have

```
  <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox moduleName" id="module110" name="module[]" value="110">
```

Comment: Did it work man? If yes, do close the question. Cheers!

Comment: No.It did not  =>``` . error TS2570: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'Client<RawResult<Element>>'. Did you forget to use 'await'?

151                 console.log(browser.getIdAttribute(elem.value.ELEMENT, 'value'));
                                                            ~~~~~
I used exactly your code

Comment: No `await` has no impact in that case. It seems that you're `elem` had no `value`, or that there is not `value` property for your `checkboxes`. But that is just a guess. Can you update the question with a complete stack-trace error? 

The example provided works indifferent of WebdriverIO version.

Comment: This is all the error that webdriverio gives. Nothing more. I added the html code to the ticket

Comment: Also I printed out the elem and i got values there:   { ELEMENT: '0.17478642349553652-8',
       'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '0.17478642349553652-8',
       selector: '.checkbox.moduleName']',
       value: [Object],
       index: 0 },  (10 elements like this)

Comment: Hey man ! Did you manage to make it work? Have you been able to do the slow&steady *[browser.debug()](http://webdriver.io/api/utility/debug.html)* approach? :) please close the question (green check mark next to answer) as that is the best & only way to achieve this. Also would be nice if you revisited some of your other questions and accept those as well, especially those where people gave you good answers & excellent solutions.

Comment: Yes. Sorry- had a busy long day. I will do that now. And I really appreciate your help. The console stuff helped a lot as well :-)

Comment: Glad to hear that @user3920295! Yeah, that functionality is really a life-saver sometimes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're `elem` will hold an `ELEMENT` object, thus you have to get the attribute via a **Protocol API** command based on the `ELEMENT` value (*id*), in our case [elementIdAttribute](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/elementIdAttribute.html).

**So try this:**

```
var checkBoxes = await $$('.checkbox.moduleName');
console.log('length', $$('.checkbox.moduleName').length);

checkBoxes.forEach((elem) => {
    console.log(elem);
    console.log(browser.getIdAttribute(elem.value.ELEMENT, 'value'));
});
```

---

**Example** (*used a page with a login form*):

```
> let tt = $$('form input');
> tt
```

> [ { ELEMENT: '0.41525845584401533-2',
>       'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '0.41525845584401533-2',
>       selector: 'form input',
>       value: { ELEMENT: '0.41525845584401533-2' },
>       index: 0 },   { ELEMENT: '0.41525845584401533-3',
>       'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '0.41525845584401533-3',
>       selector: 'form input',
>       value: { ELEMENT: '0.41525845584401533-3' },
>       index: 1 },   { ELEMENT: '0.41525845584401533-4',
>       'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '0.41525845584401533-4',
>       selector: 'form input',
>       value: { ELEMENT: '0.41525845584401533-4' },
>       index: 2 },   { ELEMENT: '0.41525845584401533-5',
>       'element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf': '0.41525845584401533-5',
>       selector: 'form input',
>       value: { ELEMENT: '0.41525845584401533-5' },
>       index: 3 } ]

```
> tt.forEach((elem) => { console.log(browser.elementIdAttribute(elem.value.ELEMENT, 'class')); })
```

> { sessionId: '1eb7b6df6484f97a9571bb93d6a95d1d', value: '_2hvTZpexuQ zyHYP', _status: 0 } 
>   { sessionId: '1eb7b6df6484f97a9571bb93d6a95d1d', value: '_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP', _status: 0 } { sessionId: '1eb7b6df6484f97a9571bb93d6a95d1d',   value: '_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP',   _status: 0 } { sessionId:
>   '1eb7b6df6484f97a9571bb93d6a95d1d',   value: '_2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP', _status: 0 }

You can further use the attribute value via the `value` property:

```
tt.forEach((elem) => { 
  let ret = browser.elementIdAttribute(elem.value.ELEMENT, 'class'); 
  console.log(`> Elem has these classes: ${ret.value}`); 
});
```

> Elem has these classes: _2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP 
>   Elem has these classes: _2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP 
>   Elem has these classes: _2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP 
>   Elem has these classes: _2hvTZ pexuQ zyHYP

Comment: interesting. My code worked right when i tried css selector 'input[name="module[]"]'. Not sure why it did not work for class name. Any wedriver.io limitation?

Comment: It shouldn't be WDIO related & the behavior should be the same for different selectors matching the same `checkbox` elems.  There are a few things you could try...

First off, put a `browser.debug()` after your page reaches the page you're automating. Then manually use the commands, one by one, reproducing the flow in the REPL interface. This will give you more understanding of the problem.

If it works that way, maybe the code executes too quickly & the HTML structure, attributes, etc, might have not been present at the time of the `elementIdAttribute()` command.

Comment: If the website is public, maybe you could share the flow so I can dive into the hood and see what's popping. 

Also, regarding selectors, mastering them will help you most. Probably the most annoying & time-consuming endeavor for web/mobile automation. You have `id`'s there too, I'd go for: `input[id^="module"]`, or `input[type="checkbox"]` & once I have that `ELEMENT` id, I'll use it to get `elementIdAttribute(elementID, 'class')`, or `elementIdAttribute(elementID, 'value')`.